# Getting Bad request error when I run a automation test of an api

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, automated-tests

Here is my code:

```
public static RestRequest CreateRequest()
    {
        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"C:\Automation\APIAutomationSuite\APIAutomationSuite\TestData\CreateReport.json"))
        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
        {
            JObject Body = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
            restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic T1NUOmxKWwag==");
            restRequest.AddJsonBody(Body);
            return restRequest;                
        }            
    }
```

When I execute the request I am getting bad request response.
With the same parameters its working fine in Postman and visual studio webtest (Loadtest).
Please help me with this.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to ensure Body has the correct values you'd expect?

Comment: Yeah, in the Body parameter I see an extra { }. These extra braces are not available in my json file. Is that the problem? Please let me know how to avoid those extra braces.

Comment: I think those extra braces came from the JsonTextReader.

Comment: Those extra braces are simply escaping the actual braces, dont worry about those